# AutoIT script works only once than it clicks on task bar rather than passing window credentials

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, autoit

I have to pass window Credentials every time I login in the Website.
**Code where AutoIT script is called:**

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","driver//chromedriver.exe");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("AutoIT_Exe//AutoIT_Login.exe");
            driver.get(url);
```

**Auto IT Script:**

```
WinWait("Sign in", "", 10)
Send("*******")
Send("{TAB}")
Send("********")
Send("{TAB}")
Send("{ENTER}")
```

[image: Window Popup in which credentials is to be passed]

Comment: Maybe you should [activate](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/WinActivate.htm) the window before `Send`?

Comment: What type of credentials? Using AutoIT prevents your code from running on non-Windows systems, and prevents it from being run when using Selenium Grid or a cloud provider. A better way would be to use a web proxy to correctly authenticate for you. I've written a [blog post series](http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.com/2019/05/handling-authentication-requests-with.html) on how to accomplish this for multiple authentication types, including basic, digest, and even using NTLM authentication.

Comment: try this _WinWaitActive ( "title" [, "text" [, timeout = 0]] )_ function instead of WinWait